# Handle templates with unknown until runtime type

Tags: c++, templates

I tried sleeping on this, but still lost. I'm not even sure what search terms I should be using. Can somebody point me in the right direction.

I want something like this:

```
template < typename Interim >
class phase_one
{
    Interim do_something () ;
}
template < typename Output, typename Interim >
class phase_two
{
    Output do_something_more ( Interim ) ;
}
template < Output >
class main_class
{
    phase_one m_first;
    phase_two m_second;

    Output do_main ( )
    {
        return m_second.dosomething_more( m_first.do_something() );
    }
}
```

Hoping you can see from the pseudocode that I need to store and call on both template classes. But the `Interim` type is not known until runtime. The only thing I know before hand is the `Output` type and the fact that both phases have a type in common.

How can I store these objects and how can I make them work together?
Is this an instance where type erasure is required?

Edit:
`phase_one` would be a `std::codecvt` and `phase_two` would be another `codecvt` of my creation. I need to select `phase_two` based on `phase_one`. And all this is done at runtime, after reading a file's BOM.

I'd prefer to do this without boost or c++11.
If there is a boost method of doing this, I would be interested in seeing it, but it must be implementable without the boost libraries, Even if I have to create a similar method/template myself.

Comment: @jogojapan A file's BOM is read and `Interim` is set to be a suitable type for reading that file, so it could be `char` `unsigned short` or `unsigned long`. The Output type would be the users required string handling type, probably `char` or `wchar_t`

Comment: @Waldermort Have you thought about using polymorphism with virtual functions? Create an "interface" for main_class and swap implementations by creating new instances of main_class.

Comment: If the number of possibilities is finite and that number is small you could force the instantiation of all the cases and then just choose the right one at runtime.

Comment: @Lalaland I would still have to hard code all the permutations and then virtual functions are going to cause a performance loss.

Comment: @Waldermort thinking that virtual functions are a performance loss is premature optimization chances are it wont change a thing. profile first optimize later.

Comment: @Borgleader sounds good in theory, but `phase_one` is actually a `std::codecvt`. If a user wants to use another locale for a file, it must be able to drop in. So the permutations are not finite.

Comment: Updated post to reflect these details.

Comment: @Waldermort How about having the clients cause more new main_classes be instantiated every time they register a new codecvt? All the main_classes could be stored in a dynamic structure like a std::map.

Comment: @Lalaland Not sure if that would work. My design idea is to create a drop in replacement for `fstream` with my own `basic_filebuf` (the main_class above). This object would derive from `basic_filebuf` but send all output through a second `codecvt`, giving the client the illusion that nothing has changed.

Comment: Why does your main class need to know about the second phase object?  At the spot where you determine the intermediate type (when you read the encoding) you have all the type info.  At that point set up the two phases and couple them.  The intermediate value never sees the light of day, because the only valid consumer is phase 2.

Comment: @Yakk Funny you say that, it's what I'm coding up at the moment. It should work, but to all the virtual methods involved it's a pain to code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified your main_class template. Basically made it aware of the `Interim` type

```
template < typename Interim >
class phase_one
{
    Interim do_something () ;
}

template < typename Output, typename Interim >
class phase_two
{
    Output do_something_more ( Interim ) ;
}

template < typename Output, typename Interim >
class main_class
{
    phase_one<Interim> m_first;
    phase_two<Output, Interim> m_second;

    Output do_main ( )
    {
        return m_second.dosomething_more( m_first.do_something() );
    }
}
```

You instantiate main_class like

```
int main () {

    if (some condition) {
         main_class<char, unsigned long> m;
         m.do_main();
    } else {
         main_class<char, unsigned short> m;
         m.do_main();
    }

}
```

Does this work for you?

Comment: m does not exist in that scope.

Comment: Silly mistake.. edited the answer. Anyway does the modified main_class template do what you want?

Comment: Some condition is only know at runtime, making the code need to compile to every interim imaginable

Comment: To this to work, you need to generate all possible permutation that interim could have. For example, one for real type, double, int, unsigned int etc....

Comment: Also (and more importantly), this solution results in an m that can only live on the stack. There is no way to hold onto m once the function returns.

Comment: I wonder if you could do the function programming approach of having the client provide a callback. Something like `void createMainClass<char,unsigned long>([](main_class<char,unsigned long> &m){ m.do_main(); doOtherThingsWithM(); etc();})`

Comment: Like Tomas said, it won't work. I cannot hard code the values, there are just too many. Also, phase_two needs to be replacable with something only the client knows, but derived from a common interface.

Comment: I could only imagine a solution that is based in polymorphism, due to the nature of problem

Comment: Then, I don't think templates are the solution for your problem. To use templates you have to know the type you want your template to be instantiated with at compile time. If this type is known only at run time you have to use dynamic polymorphism (as opposed to static/compile-time polymorphism provided by templates)

Comment: I'll accept this as the answer since it's the closest to what I ended up going with. I instead created a new template class inside `main_class` to hold the two phases and all members that need to deal with the `interim` type. The only problem remaining is storing this class and calling on it without knowing the `Interim` type at runtime. I created another question related to that problem.

Answer (score 0):

I want to propose non-C++ solution.

For this scenario, I want to say you need to know what the possible type of Interim.

Even for language like C# and Java, which can got type at runtime, you still need to clear know the possible type set, else how you make sure your code make sense for that type?

So base on @ubi answere, write an switch to handle it, and if the cost is high to write an large switch-case to handle every type, suggest you write an script tool to  generate the code from an possible Interim type list when your compile your project.

Answer (score 0):

I know you don't *want* boost, but [boost::variant](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/variant.html) can perhaps help you here. It allows you to define a "union" type, where your variable can store one of many possible types. To that you can then apply a function (called a "visitor") that is run-time determined depending on what type of data is actually stored in the variant. I've found it gets really unwieldy very quickly, but it might help you.

I'm picturing you defining your `m_first` as a `boost::variant` and then using declaring your `phase_one::do_something` as the `operator()` of a "visitor" class, so your line would become something like:

```
Output do_main ( )
{
    return m_second.dosomething_more(
       boost::apply_visitor( phase_one(), m_first ) );
}
```

Maybe it's not what you're looking for, but something to consider.